# Creating reactive vaues in loops Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, reactive

I am trying to create reactive values in loops basically I want to read 10 csv files for different country( hence the input[[paste0('country', i)]]) 
how can I create reactive values cars_i till cars_10 
And if I had one reactive values I would access the lists inside them by calling
cars()$getcols

But If I have 10 how can I call them. Would it be cars[i]$getcols?

```
 lapply(1:10, function(i) {

paste0('cars', i)<- reactive({    
cars<-fread(paste(input[[paste0('country', i)]],"cars.csv",sep = "")) 
list(Name=cars$Name,Category=cars$Category,getcols=names(cars))
})
})
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/README.html#what-is-a-reprex), as asked by the R tag (hover over it), and format your code + description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
data <- reactive({ lapply(1:10, function(i) read.csv(paste0("country_", i, ".csv"))) })
```

You can access the data like this

```
data()[[1]]  # country_1
data()[[2]]  # country_2
```

Comment: Thanks!! this worked. I was confusing myself by doing reactive inside lapply

Comment: Happy to help. Hopefully it'll help with your next reactive expressions as well